Where does Mahler 4 mvt1 borrow from Brahms and Weber?
In Recollections of Gustav Mahler, Bauer-Lechner writes:

While Mahler was still working on the first movement, he told me that he was annoyed by two reminiscences which had slipped into it and which he had noticed too late to remove. One was from a symphony by Brahms (who had, however, taken it from Weber: 'whom, consequently, we've both robbed'); the other from a Beethoven piano concerto.

I've been trying to find these "reminiscences" with no luck. Anyone have any leads?
